# Variable string name for file not working?

Tags: c

So i'm trying to write a function that will open a differnt file depending on when it was called, but when i check the file name that I'm trying to use I get a weird non acii character, must be a problem with snprint.

```
char name[20];
sprintf(name,"file_part%d", 6); //likely problem here.
FILE *file=fopen(name,"r"); //this doesn't work
printf("name is : %s", name); // and this prints a weird symbol on the terminal
```

Comment: You get a weird non-ASCII character because you've asked `printf` to print the first byte of the *address* of `name`. Try `printf("name is : %s\n", name);` `%c` prints an 8-bit value as a character. `%s` prints a string.

Comment: I'm sorry, It should have been s, but the file still doesn't open, which is the real problem, the print was just for debugging.

Comment: Please explain *doesn't open*. Did you check the value of `file` after the `fopen` call? Is it `NULL`? Or what?

Comment: where do you get the contents of name from? With just the code here, it contains uninitialized rubbish (if in a function), or the empty string. Probably the problem is with where you get name, not with fopen.

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("name is : %c", name); // and this prints a weird symbol on the terminal
```

The `%c` format specifier is for printing a character, but `name` is an array of characters terminated by an ASCII nul (also called a C-style string). For strings, use `%s`, not `%c`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more clear. That did fix the acii character but it still doesn't open the file correctly.

Comment: What does that mean? Does it open the file incorrectly?